# Show that if $B$ is a maximal abelian subalgebra of a unital Banach algebra $A$.Then $B$ is closed and contains the unit.

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Show that if $B$ is a maximal abelian subalgebra of a unital Banach algebra $A$.

Then $B$ is closed  and contains the unit.

How to approach this. $\bar B$ is closed abelian subalgebra which contain $B$. also we have $$B_1=\{b+\lambda1: b\in B ,\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\}$$ which also contain $B$ and also contain unity. But how to connect them to $B$ and show $B$ contain unity and is closed.

Any suggestion.Thanks in Advanced

Comment: you can consider $\bar B_1$, again abelian.

Comment: @orangeskid then what ?please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to prove both at once; take things one step at a time.

Let $B$ be a maximal abelian subalgebra of $A$.  Assume $B$ is not closed.  Then it's closure is abelian, and properly contains $B$, contradicting maximality of $B$.

Now assume $B$ is not unital.  Then $\{b+\lambda1:b\in B,\lambda\in\mathbb C\}$ is abelian, and properly contains $B$, again contradicting maximality of $B$.

Comment: its closure is abelian and properly contain $B$. then how it contradicting maximality  of $B$. its closure can be whole space also ??

Comment: Is that not allowed?

Comment: i donot know exactly the definition of maximal subalgebra of an algebra. what is definition of maximal subalgebra?

Comment: A maximal abelian subalgebra doesn't have to be proper.  Thus if $A$ is a abelian Banach algebra, then it has a unique maximal abelian subalgebra, namely itself.